# EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance() equivalent Updating Project from Enterprise Library 5 to 6

Tags: vb.net, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5, enterprise-library-6

Alrighty, so I'm working on an older application that was built using Enterprise Library 5 and am updating it to use the latest version (6.0.1304). However, I'm running into an issue in a few of the data access pieces that are trying to use EnterpriseLibraryContainer like so:
EnterpriseLibraryContainer.GetInstance(Of Database)(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SomeDatabaseWeUse").Name)

My question is, what is an example of replacing this older code?
I did see this

> The bootstrapping code for all of the blocks has changed in version 6 of Enterprise Library. The blocks no longer use Unity to manage the initialization and configuration, and each block now includes its own bootstrapping code. Any calls to the EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance method to resolve a type from one of the Enterprise Library blocks should be replaced with the block specific bootstrap code.>

Buuuuut I couldn't find any examples particular to GetInstance so maybe I completely understand what it means to replace it with block specific code :x

Answer (score 0):

Solution I ended up using:

```
Dim factory As DatabaseProviderFactory = New DatabaseFactory

db = factory.Create(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SomeDatabaseWeUse").Name)
```